# How to edit canonical meta tag for category from http to https in magento 1.9.x

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, canonical-link

I tried adding code in category ->custom Design->Custom Layout update

```
<reference name=”head”>
    <action method=”addLinkRel”>
       <rel>canonical</rel>
          <href>https://yourwebsiteadress.co.uk/page-name.html</href>
    </action>
</reference>
```

but it is not working.....

Is there any alternative way to convert all http to https without manually adding code into it.
If i am trying to adding this syntax catalog-> manage categories -> Custom Design ->custom layout update showing **xml data is invalid**
please help me out i am new in magento

Comment: Btw, your XML is invalid because of the quotes char - it's not the standard one. It should be ASCII code 34.

Answer (score 0):

### Default way

If you use the default theme and doesn't change it too much, it should not need manually adding codes, go to "`admin - system - Configuration - GENERAL - Web - Use Secure URLs in Frontend`", set it as "**Yes**".

Go to "`admin - system - Configuration - Catalog - Catalog - Search Engine Optimizations - Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Categories`", set it as "**Yes**".

Then it would work.

### Manually add canonical

The "`admin - system - Configuration - Catalog - Catalog - Search Engine Optimizations - Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Categories`" dropdown should be set to **No**, so that you can manually add canonical tags to Custom Layout Update box on your category page.

```
<reference name=”head”>
<action method=”addLinkRel”>
<rel>canonical</rel>
<href>https://example.com/page-name.html</href>
</action>
</reference>
```

Your "Custom Layout" codes should be "https...", you write it as "http", lack "s".

Comment: have already set it as "yes" in Use Secure URLs in Frontend still not working ,please provide another ways

Comment: @user6847618 Did you set your site default url "https"? I mean when you visit your page http, it will 301 redirect to https?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the below code in  magento root .htaccess file under `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`  tag which redirect all the http url on https

```
## HTTP to HTTPS redirection
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/downloader.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/downloader.*$
```